# Resizing a skewed rectangle from corner

Tags: c#, image

I'm working on a way to resize images by dragging the corners. It should work on rotated and skewed images.

This works so far as long as the image is a perfect rectangle. Once I add a skew to it it breaks, but I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Added comments to try to explain my current implementation.

```
//_originPosition is the position of the mouse before the drag
//_originVector is the position of every corner before the drag
//In this case:
//0 = bottom left corner, 1 = top left, 2 = top right, 3 = bottom right

Vector3 positionOffset = _originPosition - mousePosition;

var xDirection = (_originVector[3] - _originVector[0]).normalized;
var yDirection = (_originVector[1] - _originVector[0]).normalized;

//The distance in a specific direction
var xDifference = Vector3.Dot(xDirection, positionOffset);
var yDifference = Vector3.Dot(yDirection, positionOffset);

//The new position
var xPosition = -xDifference * xDirection;
var yPosition = -yDifference * yDirection;

ImageDrawer.SelectedImage.Corner[0] = _originVector[0] - positionOffset;
ImageDrawer.SelectedImage.Corner[1] = _originVector[1] + xPosition;
ImageDrawer.SelectedImage.Corner[3] = _originVector[3] + yPosition;
```

It works on a normal rectangle, and if its rotated.
[image: Normal resize]
**Rotated image:**
[image: Rotated image]
**Skewed image, this is where its wrong:**
[image: Skewed image]

Thankful for any ideas!

Comment: Looks like it's continuing to skew from the original image to the resized boundry - so without knowing how you are applying the skew i don't think people can help you.

Comment: In this case the only thing skew does is moving the 0 and 1 corners in the Y axis. It has already been applied to the rectangle, so it shouldn't affect the resize (other than not being a perfect rectangle any more). The image processing is handled elsewhere, based on the corner values